# JPA - Native @Query parameters

Tags: spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I'm trying to query all rows updated in the last N (interval parameter) seconds. It seems that ***:interval*** is not being replaced making the SQL statement parse to fail

```
@Modifying
@Query(value = "SELECT * " +
               "FROM status " +
               "WHERE updated_at >= (SYSDATE - INTERVAL ':interval' SECOND)",
       nativeQuery = true)
List<Status> findLastUpdates(@Param("interval") Integer interval);
```

Exception:

```
Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLDataException: Cannot parse "INTERVAL" constant ":interval"; SQL statement:
SELECT * FROM status WHERE updated_at >= (SYSDATE - INTERVAL ':interval' SECOND) [22007-200]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:457) ~[h2-1.4.200.jar:1.4.200]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:429) ~[h2-1.4.200.jar:1.4.200]
```

(...)

```
Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ":interval"
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65) ~[na:1.8.0_242]
    at java.lang.Long.parseLong(Long.java:589) ~[na:1.8.0_242]
```

Removing the quotes that wrappers ***:interval*** just change the exception

```
org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLSyntaxErrorException: Syntax error in SQL statement "SELECT * FROM STATUS WHERE UPDATED_AT >= (SYSDATE - INTERVAL ? SECOND[*])"; expected "string"; SQL statement:
SELECT * FROM status WHERE updated_at >= (SYSDATE - INTERVAL ? SECOND) [42001-200]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:453)
```

What Am I missing here?

I'm using Spring Boot 2.3.4

Answer (score 0):

It's not a `Spring` but SQL syntax problem - you've put `:interval` between single quotes and this way doesn't work at all. Given the `INTERVAL 'x' SECOND` **here** is just a syntax sugar for getting proper amount of seconds, you could change the sql like this:

```
"WHERE updated_at >= (SYSDATE - :sec*1/24/60/60)"
```

**UPD**: in your case the ':interval' parameter has been recognized as a string literal and this fact is contained in a stack trace:

> Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLDataException: Cannot parse "INTERVAL"
> constant ":interval"; SQL statement: SELECT * FROM status WHERE
> updated_at >= (SYSDATE - INTERVAL ':interval' SECOND) [22007-200]
>
> Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string:
> ":interval"
> at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
> ~[na:1.8.0_242]

It happened coz all the rules of String processing in java are applicable for the parameter of the `@Query` annotation. Simple example:

```
System.out.println("'Hello world!'");
```

Result: `'Hello world!' // with single quotes`

On the other hand you've got the exception after removing quotes because `INTERVAL` got a numeric value as a parameter meanwhile it expects a string value

Comment: I have updated my post with the results of removing quotes. It still an issue. You example above works, but I'm interested in understanding what is happening with INTERVAL sintaxe.

Comment: If I keep the quotes the variables is not replaced by Spring, if I remove quotes the SQL parser complains that it was expecting a string. Is there a way to use parameters with INTERVAL?